# Perform loop and calculation on BigQuery Array type

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My original data, B is an array of INT64:

[image]

And I want to calculate the difference between B[n+1] - B[n], hence result in a new table as follow:

[image]

I figured out I can somehow achieve this by using LOOP and IF condition:

```
DECLARE x INT64 DEFAULT 0;
LOOP
 SET x = x + 1
 IF(x < array_length(table.B))
 THEN INSERT INTO newTable (SELECT A, B[OFFSET(x+1)] - B[OFFSET(x)]) from table
 END IF;
END LOOP;
```

The problem is that the above idea doesn't work on each row of my data, cause I still need to loop through each row in my data table, but I can't find a way to integrate my scripting part into a normal query, where I can

```
SELECT A, [calculation script] from table
```

Can someone point me how can I do it? Or any better way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below actually works - BigQuery

```
select * replace(
  array(select diff from (
      select offset, lead(el) over(order by offset) - el as diff
      from unnest(B) el with offset
    ) where not diff is null
    order by offset
  ) as B
)
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest() with offset` for this purpose:

```
select id, a,
       array_agg(b_el - prev_b_el order by n) as b_diffs
from (select t.*, b_el, lag(b_el) over (partition by t.id order by n) as prev_b_el
      from t cross join
           unnest(b) b_el with offset n
     ) t
where prev_b_el is not null
group by t.id, t.a
```